# I have a ComboBox control, no response at first edit and works at second time

Tags: visual-c++, combobox, mfc

Now I get a  ComboBox control, everything is OK except that:

- firstly, I selected one in a multiple-selection list box, works;
- secondly, I edit the selected text, no update,
- thirdly, I edit again then changed as I wanted.

At my program, every time selecting and editing would call a function named `ChangeControlNotify(ClistControl* pControl)` and there is a `GetTest()` in this function. The problem occurred at that function `GetTest()` because it calls `CComboBox::GetCurSel`. `GetCurSel` function should return -1 at first time edit, but it returns the selecting line number as that firstly selecting.

Does anyone know why? I think maybe there is still a handler reminding after firstly editing. But I don't know and have no idea yet. If some kindly guys help. very aprreciate. Thanks

```
_bstr_t CComboBoxListControl::GetText() 
{
    CComBSTR bstr;
    int nSel = m_comboBox.GetCurSel();
    if ((-1 == nSel) && ((m_comboBox.GetWindowLong(GWL_STYLE) & CBS_DROPDOWNLIST) != CBS_DROPDOWNLIST))
    {
        m_comboBox.GetWindowText(&bstr);
    }
    else
    {
        m_comboBox.GetLBTextBSTR(nSel, bstr.m_str);
    }
    return bstr.m_str;
}

template <bool bIsCheckListView>
void CRichListControls<bIsCheckListView>::ChangeControlNotify(CListControl* pControl)
{
    CListPosition lp = FindControlPosition(pControl);
    SetItemText(lp.GetLine(), lp.GetColumn(), pControl->GetText(), false);
    CRichListControlData data(m_hWnd, lp);
    SendMessage(m_wndContained.m_hWnd, 
                WM_RICHLISTCONTROLS_MESSAGE, 
                WPARAM(rmtModify), 
                reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&data));
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. At least try to use standard classes to duplicate the problem. Comment: Use `CString` instead of `CComboBSTR` and `_bstr_t`.

Comment: Thanks for you comment @BarmakShemirani. It's a bug of an old product which code was programed in 2007. I just want to fix the bug that the control text has not changed after editing it at first time. CComboBSTR and _bstr_t were used before and in many places in projects, I can not replace them all because of afraid something bad happening.